# Django formset : Save multiple forms from formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I spent several days in order to `add dynamically forms to formset` and I find a way to do that. But I have a little issue with `forms saving` because it just saves the first form and not all forms from formset.

This is my formset :

```
DocumentFormSets = inlineformset_factory(Publication, Document, form=DocumentForm, extra=1, max_num=4)
```

This is my template :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend class="title"><span class="name">{% trans 'Document form' %}</span></legend>
    {{ DocumentFormSet.management_form }}
    <div id="form_set">
      {% for form in DocumentFormSet.forms %}
        <div class='formset-document'>
          <table class='no_error'>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{ form.language|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{ form.format|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{ form.upload|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </table>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add More" id="add_more">
    <div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
      <table class='no_error'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ DocumentFormSet.empty_form.title|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ DocumentFormSet.empty_form.language|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ DocumentFormSet.empty_form.format|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ DocumentFormSet.empty_form.upload|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This is my JS part :

```
$('#add_more').click(function () {
  var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
  $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
  $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});
```

And this is my views.py file :

```
class PublicationCreateView(EdqmCreateView):
    """ Create publication with document form through formset """
    model = Publication
    template_name = 'freepub/publication/publication_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublicationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['DocumentFormSets'] = DocumentFormSets(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formsets = context['DocumentFormSets']
        if form.is_valid() and formsets.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formsets.instance = self.object
            formsets.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But with this function, it saves only the first document form in my formset :

I looked over id document form field and I get this :

[image]

The first title field get `id_documents-0-title` but when I add more forms, title field get always `id_documents-undefined-title`

How I can save my document forms from formsets ?

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

This is an edit from @HaiLang question :

This is my `self.request.POST` :

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['0LHaaEG1dkyZmOnP3X7037tZI45QrQOIRrQQAMhiOoTyeohDwQdcdTt08yuqH86Z'], 'category': ['23'], 'pub_id': ['PUBSDDD-55'], 'title': ['TESTPUBLIE'], 'description': [''], 'doc-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'doc-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'doc-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'doc-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['4'], 'doc-0-title': ['doc1'], 'doc-0-language': ['FR'], 'doc-0-format': ['pdf'], 'doc-undefined-title': ['doc2'], 'doc-undefined-language': ['FR'], 'doc-undefined-format': ['pdf'], 'doc-__prefix__-title': [''], 'doc-__prefix__-language': [''], 'doc-__prefix__-format': [''], 'doc-__prefix__-upload': ['']}>
```

And this is my `console.log` :

```
Element kt.fn.init {}
```

Comment: to make things easier to read, you should use a plural for your formset. But why are you assigning something to `document` and saving `document` inside the for loop if `document` is your formset?

Comment: Also on which line exactly do you get the error? And show us how you construct the formset (your get_context_data)

Comment: @dirkgroten It's the first time I use formsets, so some things are a bit unclear yet. I added `get_context_data` in my question.
The issue is on line : `self.object = form.save()`

Comment: is `DocumentFormset` created using an `inlineformset_factory`?

Comment: Yes exactly ! I edited my code in order to show you missing elements.

Comment: Ok. The first version you posted without looping through the forms should work: first check if the formset is valid, then save the main `form` and assign to `self.object` then assign it to the inline formset ‘s instance and finally save the formset.

Comment: If it didn’t work there’s another problem. The best way to debug is: 1 check the html source in the browser and see that the various fields each have different ids. Then add a breakpoint in your view somewhere and check request.POST

Comment: I will try your points and see how I can do that. Unfortunately I found too few exemples with formsets and django CBV on internet.

Comment: @dirkgroten I edited some things with your previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily I just worked with FormSet recently so I can see the issue with the code in question.

(Edited by Ducky. Thank you!)

You have to set the same `prefix` between your views.py file and your app.js file. Because in your view file you are using `prefix='doc'` and in your javascript function you used `form` prefix.

So in your JQuery file you have to write :

```
(function ($) {
$('#add_more').click(function () {
    var form_idx = $('#id_doc-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    // For debugging the issue
    // console.log('Element', $('#id_doc-TOTAL_FORMS'), 'Num of forms', form_idx);
    $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_doc-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    console.log('Element', $('#id_doc-TOTAL_FORMS'));
});
})(jQuery)
```

You can overwrite your view like this :

```
class PublicationCreateView(CreateView):
    """ Create publication with document form through formset """
    model = Publication
    template_name = 'publication_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublicationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        document_queryset = Document.objects.all()
        context['DocumentFormSets'] = DocumentFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='doc', queryset=document_queryset)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formsets = context['DocumentFormSets']
        // For debugging
        // print(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formsets.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formsets.instance = self.object
            formsets.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you with your answer. But I have some black points : The first one, the print in the console is : `Num of forms undefined` each time I add a new form in my formset. I have to see why it's defined as `undefined`. Then according to your views part, if I save all at once, it saves just the first form in my formset. If I try to save one by one, it saves none documents.

Comment: So the `Num of forms undefined` in console confirms that the error is at form_idx. Now you can update the script to `console.log('Element', $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS'));` That is to confirm that the input in management_form can be retrieved. The $ sign is isgnature of jQuery. Have you include jQuery script in your HTML header?

Comment: About saving form, could you please put `print(self.request.POST)` before `formsets = ` and provide the output? That is to confirm posted data to have enough forms. I believe the statement `$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);` did not do its job to update total number of forms.

Comment: Below is my management_form in generated HTML file. It has the `id_form-TOTAL_FORMS` required by javascript. Could you please provide the same in your generated HTML file? `<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="4" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" />`

Comment: I edited my question with the console.log. JQuery is well included in my HTML and the `print(self.request.POST)` too.

Comment: Be careful, I'm workin with Django class based view ^^

Comment: Could you please update `id_form-TOTAL_FORMS` in javascript to `id_doc-TOTAL_FORMS`? That is because in your management_form, it use `doc` instead of `form`.

Comment: You found the solution ! It was this issue : `prefix` from my view (doc) and `prefix` used in my app.js (form) which were different !